# Start PHPmyAdmin from putty - Server is remote

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, putty

Bit stuck here, I have looked on here, for similar, but cant find what I need. 
Have looked at how to start PHPmyAdmin via putty on here.

I have a server, which is on a network. I log into the network via Putty. 
The database usual access is for example 10.32.187.100/m . This is how I used to access it before the server reboot.

I have had to restart the server. But I cannot log into the database as I believe I have to turn it on.

As it is not on a local machine I do not know how. It is a linux server, and the location of ‘m’ is /var/www/html

In ‘m’ are the files for phpmyAdmin.

Nothing has been over written. The server had to restart. Hence why I need to start up PHPmyAdmin.

Can I ask how do I turn on PHPmyAdmin via putty I the method I need to use?

Comment: what os you are using and what web server?

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is just a web app. what you may want is to start the mysql server. to do that, `service mysql start` usually works, but might depend on your system. Also, you will need root access

Comment: Hi Alex & Ebrahim, The OS is Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. It is not on a web server. It is on a server on site. I have VPN access to it.

Comment: do you have folder /etc/apache or /etc/nginx ?

Comment: i have etc/apache2

Comment: Sounds like your web server isn't running, most likely it is running either Apache or Nginx. When you try to go to that URL are you getting anything at all or just a page cannot be found? If you are getting a login page but you just can't login then most likely mysql isn't running.

Comment: try running `sudo service apache2 start`

Comment: if starting/restarting Apache isn't it.. is it possible this system got a new random IP  (not 10.32.187.100) ?

Comment: also if mysql isn't running `sudo service mysql start`

Comment: Have input sudo service apache2 start and then asked me for password, which i input. It then just whet to the next line, it accepted the password. But it is still the same. (next line is place@place-01P:~$) .  In the apache2 folder under 'sites-enabled' there is a config file for our system place-ssl.conf, in this also has the name of the webapp which runs on the server. However the DB location when I load it up is m/ which is located in var/www/html/m

Comment: Duane, I can ping the server and get up the files on the server via putty etc. The IP is static.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo service mysql start
sudo service apache2 start
```

Comment: I input the above. mysql start went in fine. apache start I got error 'Failed to start apache.service: Unit apache.service not found. I input apache2 start and that went in fine.

Comment: Ebrahim, We are up and running, THANK YOU

Comment: :) if your problem is solved you can check this answer as correct